# No component factory found for NotificationsListComponent

Tags: angular

this is my module structure in angular...

Landing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [LandingComponent],
imports: [CommonModule, HeadersidebarModule, LandingRoutingModule
],
```

})

Landing.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

HeaderSidebar.moduele.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule, MatProgressBarModule, NotificationsModule
],
declarations: [
    HeaderComponent, SidebarComponent
],
exports: [HeaderComponent, SidebarComponent]
```

})

header.component.html

```
<app-notifications></app-notifications>
```

Notifications.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [NotificationsComponent, NotificationsListComponent],
imports: [
    CommonModule, MatBadgeModule, MatIconModule,
],
exports: [NotificationsComponent],
entryComponents: [NotificationsListComponent],
```

})

Notifications.component.ts
trying to load the notificationlist.component.ts dynamically and mention the notificationlistcomponent in entrycomponents array of @NgModule () of Notification.module.ts but still getting the error,

Please Help...

Error is ->

> ERROR Error: No component factory found for
>   NotificationsListComponent. Did you add it to
>   @NgModule.entryComponents?
>       at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:7754)
>       at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory
>   (core.js:7792)
>       at DomPortalOutlet.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/portal.es5.js.DomPortalOutlet.attachComponentPortal
>   (portal.es5.js:409)
>       at DomPortalOutlet.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/portal.es5.js.BasePortalOutlet.attach
>   (portal.es5.js:296)
>       at OverlayRef.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js.OverlayRef.attach
>   (overlay.es5.js:995)
>       at OverlayService.push../src/app/shared/services/overlay_.service.ts.OverlayService.open
>   (overlay_.service.ts:63)
>       at NotificationsComponent.push../src/app/shared/notifications/notifications.component.ts.NotificationsComponent.openNotnListOverlay
>   (notifications.component.ts:41)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (NotificationsComponent.html:2)
>       at handleEvent (core.js:19545)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20639)

Comment: add ``entryComponents:[]`` in ``NgModule`` of app.module.ts and declare ``NotificationComponent``

Comment: LandingModule is lazily loaded, can't add to entry components of NgModule of app.module.ts

Comment: can't add notificationlist component to entry components of ngmodule of appmodule,  because notificationlist component is part of notificationModule..

Comment: How are you trying to load the NotificationsListComponent? If you can, create a stackblitz reproduction of the problem please.

Comment: const dialogConfig = { ...DEFAULT_CONFIG, ...config };
        const overlayRef = this._createOverlay(dialogConfig);
        const filePreviewPortal = new ComponentPortal(component, viewContRef);
        const compRef: ComponentRef<T> = overlayRef.attach(filePreviewPortal); using cdk overlay API trying to load the NotificationsListComponent and on the click I invoke this instructions in NotificationComponent... and Add NotificationListComponent in entryComponent array of NotificationModule, rest you see code above...

Comment: solved this problem by eagerly loading the LandingModule, but if lazy Load the landingModule only then i get this error ...